# How can I center the placeholder and text box cursor after shrinking the placeholder text?

Tags: html, css

I have an input text box with the placeholder text inside; right now, I'm shrinking the placeholder text so that it is still visible when the text box is focused, but when I shrink it, and despite the vertical translation, the placeholder text is too close to the top of the input box.

I understand that the cursor in the text box is still centered, but I'd like for **both** the placeholder text and cursor to be centered within the text box. Is there a way to do this with just CSS?

// My input text box:

```
<input
  type="text"
  className={errors.email && errors.email.length !== 0 ? 'bad-input' : ''}
  value={this.state.email}
  onChange={this.update('email')}
  placeholder="Email"
/>
```

// My styling to shrink the placeholder text:

```
.login-modal-wrapper form .main-content-wrapper input[type="text"]:focus::placeholder,
.login-modal-wrapper form .main-content-wrapper input[type="password"]:focus::placeholder {
  font-size: 12px;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For horizontally center, you should use `text-align:center`.

For vertically adjustments, You need to manually set them but there are 2 options;

1. You could adjust the padding of the textbox; `padding-top:10px;` or `padding-top:40%;`
2. Adjust line-height of the texts inside the textbox; `line-height:20px;`.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean adding the `padding-top` to the `input[type="text"]` selector?

Comment: @Karen sorry, wasn't able to understand completely. I added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question again, this time I understood that by adjusting the font size of the placeholder, will affect its vertical alignment relative to the text inside the input field.

You could adjust the placeholder pseudo class by using `position:relative` and changing the `top` property;

See example below;

```css
input::placeholder {
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label>
    <input style="height:100px; width:200px;" type="text" id="fname" placeholder="test" name="fname"><br><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```